# Take the number from brackets

Tags: python

I want to take the integer from the brackets and erase the rest.

So, I want to transform `[u'20']` into `[20]`

Comment: "[u'20']" is also a string?

Comment: Yes, it is. @Corralien

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what data type it is but I've made an attempt

```
start = [u'20']
start = str(start)
mid = start.replace('u','')
end = mid.replace("'",'')
print(end)
```

or more globally

```
start = [u'20']
start = str(start)
sub = start[2:4]
end = '['+ sub + ']'
print(end)
```

Comment: Is there any way to it more global? I mean independently whether I've an ''u'' character or ''x'', etc

Answer (score 0):

Using [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re

s = "[u'20'] [x'40']"
l = [int(n) for n in re.findall(r"\w+'(\d+)'", s)]
```

```
>>> l
[20, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "[u'20']"
print(f"""[{text.strip("[]u'")}]""")
```

**Output:**

```
[20]
```